# How can I implement a JNA interface to an LPVOID buffer?

Tags: winapi, jna

I'm trying to implement a JNA interface to [VerQueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647464.aspx) from the Windows API.

It has the following native signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI VerQueryValue(
  __in   LPCVOID pBlock,
  __in   LPCTSTR lpSubBlock,
  __out  LPVOID *lplpBuffer,
  __out  PUINT puLen
);
```

I seem to have successfully converted three of the parameters (1 - Pointer, 2 - WString, 4 - IntByReference), but I'm stuck with the third.

What is the correct translation, and how can I access the information stored in that buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tend to say the correct mapping will be :

```
int VerQueryValue(Pointer pBlock, String lpSubBlock, PointerByReference lplpBuffer, IntByReference puLen);
```

Since I never used *VerQueryValue* the code below is a guess on how to use the result :

```
//other parameters & method calls ...
//empty constructor : VerQueryValue will valuate the pointed value.
PointerByReference lplpBuffer = new PointerByReference();
//empty constructor : VerQueryValue will valuate the pointed value.
IntByReference puLen = new IntByReference ();
int rc = YourClassName.VerQueryValue(pBlock,lpSubBlock,lplpBuffer,puLen);
//Check rc & co
//use the result
byte[] resBytes = lplpBuffer.getValue().getByteArray(0,puLen.getValue());
//if it's a String
String resString = new String(resBytes, ENCODING);
```